# Javascript ООП метод не возвращает значение из функции

Tags: javascript, node.js, ооп, context, this

```js
class Database
{

getAll()
{
  this.connect().query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1', 
  (err, res , fields) => {
    if(err) throw err;
  
    return res;
  });
  }
}
```

метод getAll Должен возвращать все данные из таблицы table, но почему то возвращает undefined.
Данные в этой переменной есть, тут какой прикол с потерей контекста что ли? Я не могу понять.

*Решение с помощью промисов*

```js
   let promise = new Promise(
   (resolve, reject) => {
        this.connect.query(`SELECT * FROM trainee WHERE 1`,
        (err , result , fields) => {
        resolve(JSON.stringify(result));
        reject(err);
      });
    });
    return promise;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Database
{

getAll()
{
  return this.connect().query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1', 
  (err, res , fields) => {
    if(err) throw err;

    return res;
  });
  }
}
```

Comment: Возвращает функцию query , но не res. Может как то к ней надо обратится?

Comment: Тогда: this.connect(); return this.query(...

Comment: Нет так не получится. Потому что this.connect возвращает объект у которого метод query.
Я уже решил задачу с помощью промисов.

Comment: @singlesly поделитесь решением. Интересно увидеть

Comment: Добавил в вопрос.